# Ubuntu Touch - Mobile Data becoming increasingly unusable

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Over the last few weeks I have noticed that the mobile data on my E5 Ubuntu phone keeps on dropping out, to the point that it is becoming increasingly unusable. I know that there have been issues raised about the WiFi. However, I am not sure if anyone else is experiencing issues like this with their mobile data. When my data goes the only thing I can do, to get it back is to put the phone into air plane mode and then turn it off again. This always brings the mobile data back. Even when I am in the same place and the data signal originally was lost.

As an example; the other day my wife and I were enjoying breakfast in a coffee shop. We were sat by the window and she had full data. I had none. We are both on the same network. I turned on air plane mode and then turned it off again and the my data came back. It stayed on for a minute or so and then went off again. Air plane mode activated again and the deactivated and mobile data was returned. During this time my wife had continual signal on her Samsung S3.

Comment: Over the last few days the mobile data issue has been getting worse and worse. One day I had no data at all and when I put my phone into flight mode and then back out again the data would come back for a minute or two and then go off again. I turned my phone data to 2G yesterday and I have not had an issue all day. When the data goes, it connects again within a few seconds. Browsing is a little slow, but that's OK. It looks like the issue is when you have the 2+3G option, it does not like swamping between the two. It appears that when there is a 3G issue, the data dies & does not go to 2G.

Comment: I have been using the mobile data with the 2G option set for a bit now and apart from it being noticeable slower, it is working far better than the 2G & 3G option.

Comment: This is still a hit and miss issue. Over the last few weeks I have had to continually switch between both 2G and 3G to get any level of data service.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, i have also issues with Meizu Pro 5 and 2G/3G/4G connections.

At first issues was smaller: Connection loss, try turn air plane mode on and off. if not worked reboot device and connection works sometime. Now i boot my device and get connection <1min until phone drops connection and says "unregistered". Air plane mode does not help anymore. Reboot sometimes helps, but usually i have to turn my phone off, use my spare phone and wait for a day or so and try to connect to network again. As i posted comment here: [Meizu Pro 5 Ubuntu Edition OTA-11 - 2G/3G issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/784408/meizu-pro-5-ubuntu-edition-ota-11-2g-3g-issue), I have this issue in Finland with OTA-10.2, OTA-11 and OTA-12. I was in Sweden 4 days and network connections worked fine with OTA-10.2 and OTA-11.

I'll try to borrow a sim card from some of my friends and try to get connection and see what happens. Also i'll try to get micro sd card from somewhere so i can test sim slot 2 if that has same problems. I'll let you know does any of that solve anything.

Comment: Before the latest OTA-12 release yesterday I washaving a hell of a game with mobile data. I even changed the slots for the simply that used mobile data but nothing helped.

Comment: It has only been a day but with the latest release I have notices that ob the train home and back again this mornibg I have signal in places it was dead before. For me it does seem to be holding and maibtainibg the movile aignal a bot more. Not perfext buy it seems better than what it was. Ireally hipe that the next release keeps on building on tgis success.

Comment: Tried with 2 different sim-cards from different carriers and sim2 slot. Same problems...

Comment: That is a shame to hear that is is no better for you but at least it does pont to the phone and not the carrier. I have recently noticed that it looks like my mobile data is ok (showing 3G), bit when I do something like check updatea or send emails, the signal dies along with the phone. It takes about 30 seconds to come back. So it looks like it is ok but when you do something it dies.

Comment: Yeah, my carrier service dies also right after i start using mobile data or try to call someone. I think it is software/firmware issue cos as i said, my phone worked any notable issues at Sweden couple of days. I found some similar bug reports yesterday and im gonna try couple of things this weekend which might help.

Comment: Please let me known how it goes as I would love to resolve thia issue.

Comment: I guess that issue has something to do with ofono. I dont have linux PC in use at this weekend but im trying to get bash working on crappy Windows 10 laptop :D You can also browse those bug reports if u wanna: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/urfkill/+bug/1321627 . Anyway ill let you know when i have something.

Comment: Today i took out the second sim in my phone. I do not use it that much and i was hoping that this may make a difference. All was looking good and then when i was typing this comment, both the mobile data and phone signal died. Hope that you havr haf more luck with your data.

Comment: Sorry being inactive with this issue. I contacted reseller and going to send some video about this issue. Hope i get some info how to solve this issue. Ill try to make some configurations to ofono package this week. Ill let you know if/when i have something

Comment: I have been in the UK for the last few weeks and Ilasa result I have changed to the Tesco network. They have 4G and the best I have ever received 2G and that was only for a few minutes. My son has a Samsung and he is always on 4G. I am really hoping that the next system update can sort this out as not even getting 3G these days is going backwards.

Comment: I do not know how your mobile data issue is going, but for me I have had to give up the E5 phone and return back to my Samsung on Android. Since then (with the same provider) I have had really good reception, in places that I did not in with the E5. So I can say that it is not the provider. I am in the process of trying to contact BQ to try and get the phone replaced. i do not think I will get very far with that though. So for now, until there is another Ubuntu phone released, I am just using my BQ M10 tablet.

Comment: Issue is still on. Installed OTA-13 and i cannot get connection at all anymore. Have been sending emails to jd.com. They didnt have sollution for this issue and they said they contact manufacturer. Its been almost month now since i received last email from jd so i guess it's time to send  inquiry again...

Comment: Oh dear that is not good customer service at all. It is a shame that I have had to give up on the Touch phone as I was watching a program last night about the tracking services employed by a major phone os player and that just made me want to move to Ubuntu Touch even more, but with the network issues we are having there is no way I can.

Comment: Yeah their customer support isn't very good. If you care about privacy, you should chech out Purism: https://puri.sm/ Those guys are planning to release phone some day

Comment: Sent quite angry email to jd.com and gonna give customer feedback as well if they are not gonna get solved this soon. It's been almost 3 months now when i first contacted jd.com and getting pretty pissed off with them. Useless customer service and technical team does not know anything. Tech guys suggest to update latest firmware via link they send and that link was to firmware for Flyme OS.

Comment: Of course i told them i was using "Ubuntu Edition" so thats not gonna solve anything.  After that they said they are gonna contact manufacturer about which firmware should be installed. And that was over month ago! Really gonna seriosly consider about buying anything again from jd, even if they get this fixed...

Comment: That is a shame that you have not been able to get yourmobile data working